# Visual Studio: Variable is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

While using Visual Studio I get a run-time check failure due to a variable being used without being initialized. Something like this is going on:

```
SomeStruct ss;
SomeOtherStruct sos = {ss};
```

Later on in the code I initialize `sos.ss` before I actually use it.

I appreciate that Visual Studio catches it but this should be a warning since I don't really use it, I just pass it around and not throw a run-time exception while I'm running the program.

I am using `C` not `C++` but haven't found a way to tell VS to use C (I need to manually put .c files and uncheck use pre-compiled headers). Anyway, how can I tell VS to stop complaining about this exception. Unmarkins "break when this exception type is thrown" does not usually work (problem tends to come back).

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't type `SomeStruct ss = {0};`?

Comment: *"...but this should be a warning since I don't really use it..."* But you do use it to construct `SomeOtherStruct`

Comment: "_I am using C not C++ but haven't found a way to tell VS to use C_" Project properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As -> Compile As C Code.

Comment: Note that after this initialisation, if you change `ss` you do *not* change `sos`.  Did you perhaps mean `{*ss}` ?

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of `SomeOtherStruct sos = {ss};` is *undefined* if `ss` contains uninitialised plain old data which are not `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` types.

This is because you are reading uninitialised data in the initialisation of `sos`.

Visual Studio therefore is being very helpful.

In C, you can write `SomeStruct ss = {0};` which will fix this. In C++ you can drop the `0`. But why do you see the need to initialise `sos` from an uninitialised `ss`?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic error is that you seem to think that `SomeOtherStruct sos = {ss};` will establish a pointer or "alias" of `ss` with `sos` so that when, at some later point in your code, you initialize `ss`, you also intitialize `sos`.

But that is not the case in C. You simply copy al the values of `ss` to `sos` and since `ss` is uninitialized, you copy garbage to `sos`. And that garbage temains there even when you initialize `ss` later on.

Comment: Not really. For some reason I was under the impression I needed to pass a structure to the other structure when I declared it but it is not needed. So I can just remove `ss`, just put `SomeOtherStructure sos` and initialize its members later.